# A general formula for product of two matrices

Tags: matrices

I need to consider the matrix A, which is $m * n$ and matrix B, which is $n * p$. I've been asked to consider the product of these matrices where $A_{ij} = i-j$ and $B_{ij}= i + j$.

Using the Formula for the product of two matrices I can calculate the Matrix C: $$C_{ij} = \sum_{i=0}^n A_{i1}B_{1j} = A_{i1}B_{1j}+A_{i2}B_{2k}+ ...+A_{in}B_{nj}$$

But the problem is that the above summation does not include the internal values of matrices A & B, i.e $A_{ij} = i-j$ and $B_{ij}= i + j$. Is there a way to include the values of A and B in the summation since they follow an obvious pattern? I know how to calculate the answer, but can't figure out how to put it into a simple formula. This is a question for a homework assignment, so I'm not asking for the answer, but rather a nudge in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Guide:

\begin{align}
C_{ij} &= \sum_{\color{red}{k=1}}^n A_{i\color{red}k}B_{\color{red}kj}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n(i-k)(k+j)
\end{align}

You can now expand the summation, note that $i$ and $j$ are fixed and use the formula of $$\sum_{k=1}^n k=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$

and $$\sum_{k=1}^n k^2=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$$

to simplify the term.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It seems like the simplified term is the sum of squares, but I'm struggling to see how this relates back to each individual entry in the matrix though.

Comment: Not sure if I understand your doubt. $C_{ij}$ is the individual entry isn't it?

Comment: Lets say that n=3, how could I use this formula to obtain the value in the first row and first column, for instance? Does that make sense?

Comment: For the first row, $i=1$ and $j$ takes value from $1$ to $3$.   For the first colum, $i$ takes value from $1$ to $3$, and $j=1$   You should work with arbitrary $i$ and $j$, that is obtain an expression in terms of $i$, $j$ and $n$.

Comment: Thanks for your help :)